# How to apply layout constraints to in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: layout, windows-phone-8.1

How can I apply layout constraints to layout so that it auto adjusts it self for every device like we apply in iOS?
The app I developed leaves blank spaces when I run it on higher size devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several techniques you can use. Which is best depends on your app's specific design:

- Use a fluid control such as GridView or ListView which will expand to fill the available space.
- Use a relative size layout control such as a Grid to lay things out by percentages.
- Use Visual States to choose different controls or layouts for different size or aspect ratio screens
- Use a ViewBox to stretch a layout to fit

Windows 10 adds a few new controls that can help:

- RelativePanel to specify control locations relative to other controls (on top off, to the left of, etc.)
- Adaptive triggers to automatically switch Visual States based on window size changes

See [Defining layouts and views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465329.aspx) on MSDN for details and quickstarts.

There were several sessions at Build 2015 which touched on this subject, although more aimed at Windows 10 capabilities than at Windows Phone 8.1